# Eclipse, C/C++ ,Link two projects in the same workspace

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am using eclipse for programming c.
I would like to link two different projects in my workspace.
For example, I have a project named List and I would like to create a project named Inventory which uses List. I would like to link the two projects so that all I have is to do is
include "list.h". What is the proper way of doing that in eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT C/C++: Include a header file from another project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272882/eclipse-cdt-c-c-include-a-header-file-from-another-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT C/C++: Include a header file from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272882/eclipse-cdt-c-c-include-a-header-file-from-another-project)

Answer (score 2):

Some one asked the same question this morning on this post :[Question about CDT and multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272882/eclipse-cdt-c-c-include-a-header-file-from-another-project/9273145#9273145)

Just look at the answer I did to Bittenus

Comment: If you don't want to learn cmake, you can do like Bittenus said in the thread.
But to learn cmake you can start here : http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html